# Was any product in Jurassic Park's Gallimimus Gift Shop available as a real world purchase?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, jurassic-park

Towards the end of the first *Jurassic Park* movie, when Tim, Lex and Alan enter the Visitor Centre and the children go to eat food. The 'Gallimimus Gift Shop' is briefly shown.

The [Jurassic-Pedia](https://www.jurassic-pedia.com/gift-shop-memorabilia-sf/) states that the store contains the following items:

- Lunchboxes
- Stuffed dinosaur toys
- Children’s pajamas
- Books on Tyrannosaurus
- Jurassic Park stamp set
- Making of Jurassic Park book
- Dinosaur drink bottles
- Gift bags
- Cushions with images of cartoon
  dinosaurs on them.

Some of these items can be seen in the following images, from the film.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Did any of these exact products exist as real items that the moviegoing public at the time of the film's release in 1993, would have been able to purchase?

Comment: Good lord no. That would have just been tacky.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The in-universe book "*[The Making of Jurassic Park by Don Shay and Jody Duncan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GsKp.png)*" was also available in [real bookshops](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Making-Jurassic-Park-Don-Shay/dp/1852837748), published in June 1993.

[image]

---

The multi-coloured plush dinosaurs appear to have been made by a company called ***Applause***. The tyrannosaur below is [dated from 1992](https://www.cafr.ebay.ca/itm/225675189748), as is [the triceratops](https://www.ebay.com/itm/204308519652), [apatosaur](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/354449849017) and [sabre-tooth tiger](https://www.ebay.com/itm/304582720499).

[image] [image] [image]

---

The [thermos flasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQoYo.jpg), [binders](https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/5851f423-3ac3-4eef-88d5-2be0fc69382b/dfxlms5-5bef89b7-9f43-4b04-9bb1-54e149201ab0.png/v1/fill/w_1280,h_2160,q_80,strp/jurassic_park_gift_shop_by_mdwyer5_dfxlms5-fullview.jpg?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9MjE2MCIsInBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcLzU4NTFmNDIzLTNhYzMtNGVlZi04OGQ1LTJiZTBmYzY5MzgyYlwvZGZ4bG1zNS01YmVmODliNy05ZjQzLTRiMDQtOWJiMS01NGUxNDkyMDFhYjAucG5nIiwid2lkdGgiOiI8PTEyODAifV1dLCJhdWQiOlsidXJuOnNlcnZpY2U6aW1hZ2Uub3BlcmF0aW9ucyJdfQ.rbXkIezjZ9wlx3tA4iXLtqXS3nEcvZ9hznEwS7oUQu8), lunchboxes and [stamper sets](https://www.therpf.com/forums/threads/jurassic-park.68579/post-5469058) appear to have been manufactured by a company called [***Sanrio Dinomighties***](https://sanrio.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Dinomighties). The examples below are dated to [1986](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/vintage-sanrio-tyrannosaurus-dinosaur-2005725139) - [1990](https://picclick.com/Vtg-1990-Sanrio-Tyrannosaurus-Thermos-Dinomighties-Dinosaur-Tyrannosaurus-305203362913.html).

[image] [image]

Comment: From what I can tell, everything branded "Jurassic Park" was made custom by the film's propmakers. The rest of the dinosaur crap was stuff that they bought from local toy shops, probably in the Hollywood area.

Comment: Funnily, this makes it very realistic. Real tourist attractions also tend to mix branded merchandise with unbranded stuff that vaguely fits the theme.

Comment: At bout this time my sister's store sold, among other things, plush dinosaurs which looked at lot like those.